# Elasticsearch: find documents with at least 2 matching terms

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I've a big list of people and projects they've worked on together.

Now I want to find all of the projects in which at least 2 out of 5 specific people worked on together as part of a team.

I know I can use the `terms` query to find all of the projects in which at least 1 of the 5 worked on.

Is it possible to also limit the results to those projects where 2 or more of the team members are part of the 5 people?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able take a look on [Terms Set Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html). It is similar to [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-terms-query.html) mentioned by you but you should be able to use [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) parameter (setting it to 2) and have what you want.